# SSAS XMLA DISCOVER: how to get list of roles in SSAS database

Tags: sql, ssas, roles, xmla

I am trying to get a list of roles existing in an SSAS DB using XMLA. I need only roles, not other information.

I know there is a `<RequestType>DISCOVER_XML_METADATA</RequestType>`:

```
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">  
   <RequestType>DISCOVER_XML_METADATA</RequestType>  
   <Restrictions>
       <RestrictionList xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
           <DatabaseID>SSAS_DB_ID</DatabaseID>
       </RestrictionList>
   </Restrictions>  
   <Properties>  
      <PropertyList>
      </PropertyList>  
   </Properties>  
</Discover>
```

The query returns a ~9Mb XML containing **complete information** about the database, including the information that I do not need.

Yes, it does contain the piece with the roles:

```
...
     <Roles>
        <Role>
          <Name>ROLE_NAME_AND_ID1</Name>
          <ID>ROLE_NAME_AND_ID1</ID>
          <CreatedTimestamp>2020-05-13T11:20:27.343333</CreatedTimestamp>
          <LastSchemaUpdate>2020-06-03T06:16:53.816667</LastSchemaUpdate>
          <Description />
          <Members>
            <Member>
              <Sid>SID1</Sid>
              <Name>DOMAIN\LOGIN1</Name>
            </Member>
            <Member>
              <Sid>SID2</Sid>
              <Name>DOMAIN\LOGIN2</Name>
            </Member>
          </Members>
        </Role>
      </Roles>
...
```

But I would like to have only the role list without anything else.

Could not find a clear explanation on the web or MS website (where the documentation is extremely quirky for me) and would appreciate any insights.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:**
I needed to use the list of roles and members in a SQL procedure. I managed to use the result of `DISCOVER_XML_METADATA` in a procedure. Below is working code.

Still, it has to load the complete XML_METADATA from SSAS (instead of just roles, as I intended in the main question), but it works.

```
declare @SSASDBName nvarchar(255) = 'SSAS_DB_NAME'

-- when executed from SQL, XMLA Discover has to be wrapped in <Batch>
declare @XMLA nvarchar(MAX)
select @XMLA = '<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine" Transaction="true">
<Discover xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">  
   <RequestType>DISCOVER_XML_METADATA</RequestType>  
   <Restrictions>
       <RestrictionList xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis">
           <DatabaseID>'+@SSASDBName+'</DatabaseID>
       </RestrictionList>
   </Restrictions>
   <Properties/>
</Discover></Batch>'

-- get the XML response from SSAS
declare @t table (x XML)
insert @t
EXEC(@XMLA) AT LINKED_SSAS_SERVER -- linked SSAS server

declare @XMLAResult xml
select @XMLAResult = x from @t

-- expand XML response
;with XMLNAMESPACES (default 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-analysis:rowset')
select
    SSAS_DB                     = X_DB.x.query('./ID').value('.','nvarchar(255)'),
    RoleID                      = X_Roles.x.query('./ID').value('.','nvarchar(255)'),
    RoleMember                  = X_Members.x.query('.').value('.','nvarchar(255)')
from @XMLAResult.nodes('//Database') X_DB(x)
cross apply @XMLAResult.nodes('//Roles/Role') X_Roles(x)
cross apply X_Roles.x.nodes('./Members/Member/Name') X_Members(x)
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07mt1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the  DMVs `$SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_ROLES` & `$SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_ROLE_MEMBERSHIPS`. You can query using `Invoke-ASCmd`

e.g.

```
$serverUri="server.asazure.windows.net/model"

Invoke-ASCmd -Server $serverUri -Query "select * from `$SYSTEM.TMSCHEMA_ROLES"
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add this free open-source [ASSP](https://asstoredprocedures.github.io/ASStoredProcedures/) assembly to your server or database and then run the following (see this example and other role related ones [here](https://asstoredprocedures.github.io/functions/DiscoverXmlMetadata/)):

```
CALL ASSP.DiscoverXmlMetadata("\Database\Roles\Role");
```

Another option is to use this free open-source Visual Studio extension [BI Developer Extensions](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io) which can generate a [roles report](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/RolesReport/) which you can export to PDF. The advantage of this option is it queries Active Directory to recursively expand groups to see the members.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen ASSP mentioned quite a few times. The problem is I cannot install additional assemblies on SSAS server. Also, I have not mentioned that I need to call the XMLA from SQL procedure. Will update my question now.